# How to parse today's date into a parameter

Tags: sql, impala

I want to create a parameter with today's date in order to add it in my queries in an sql script. I tried the below:

```
${var:id_date} =  from_timestamp(date_trunc('second', now()),'yyyyMMdd');
```

But I am facing the below issue.

> ParseException: Syntax error in line 1:undefined: ${var:id_date} =
> select from... ^ Encountered: IDENTIFIER Expected: ALTER, COMMENT,
> COMPUTE, COPY, CREATE, DELETE, DESCRIBE, DROP, EXPLAIN, GRANT, INSERT,
> INVALIDATE, LOAD, REFRESH, REVOKE, SELECT, SET, SHOW, TRUNCATE,
> UPDATE, UPSERT, USE, VALUES, WITH CAUSED BY: Exception: Syntax error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When setting variable use `set var:id_date=...;`

```
set var:id_date=from_timestamp(date_trunc('second', now()),'yyyyMMdd');

    select * from mytable where id_date=${var:id_date};
```

Comment: I tried also with set but I take this error back :

ParseException: Syntax error in line 1:undefined: set var:id_date=from_timestamp(date... ^ Encountered: : Expected: ADD, ALTER, AND, ARRAY, AS, ASC, BETWEEN, BIGINT, BINARY, BLOCK_SIZE, BOOLEAN, CACHED, CASCADE, CHANGE, CHAR, COMMENT, COMPRESSION, CROSS, DATE, ......: Exception: Syntax error

Comment: @Thkas It should work only in impala-shell. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IMPALA-2180